# semantics of X cursor shapes

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, semantics, mouse-cursor, xorg

In a GUI application I co-develop, we have a bit of trouble with using cursors.
That is: we are not happy with the way how some cursors are displayed if certain icon themes are installed.

The software is a graph editor written in Tcl/Tk, where you can connect nodes with your mouse.
If you hover the mouse over a node, the cursor changes (indicating that you can create a connection):

[image: circle cursor in action]

At some point in the past, we decided that from all the available cursors, the `circle` cursor (as [provided by TclTk](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/cursors.html)) is the best match for our requirement.

According to https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/appendix/b/, the `circle` cursor looks like, well, a *circle* on X11. TclTk will indeed render the `circle` cursor as a *circle* on macOS, Windows and (sometimes) Linux.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is some rough consensus between various icon themes available in Linux Distributions, that the `circle` cursor has a *semantic* meaning that goes beyond a simple "circle", but instead should have a negative connotation of "not possible" or "forbidden", and displays as something associated with :

- KDE: [image: Oxygen theme]
- Gnome: [image: Adwaita theme]

This "*not allowed*" cursor is irritating our users, as it is used to indicate a positive "*now you can do something*".

On macOS and Windows this is not a problem. AFAICT at least on Windows, the `circle` cursor is provided by Tk itself (rather than relying on a system cursor).

So my question is: Who is at the fault here?

- The application using the `circle` cursor, assuming the wrong semantics?
- The cursor theme, assigning an arbitrary (but specific) meaning to an icon that is *not* defined semantically
- The toolkit engine (Tcl/Tk), because they suggest a cursor with some (or no) meaning, but pass it on to a renderer that uses a different (or some) meaning?

Where are the semantics of the X11-cursors defined? Should a `circle` cursor be just a *circle* (and the semantics come from the application; so there's really not much freedom for a cursor theme designer)? Or is it just a short-hand for "do not enter" (and the cursor fonts are free to express them at their will)?

(I guess the problem is grounded in history: originally cursors did not have a semantic meaning at all. They were just what their name suggested (thus the `circle` cursor would be nothing but a *circle*) and an application was free to add meaning to that shape.
But in the last decades things have shifted toward semantic icons (that allow rigorous skinning). And people coming from the new school of meaningful icons started assigning meaning to icons that had no defined meaning beforehand. This is all wild conjecture on my side; and while it might explain *why* things are as they are right now, it doesn't help me how to solve my problem)

My gut feeling says that a `circle` should be a *circle*, and thus the cursor themes are at fault.
However, a quick survey of icon themes available in Debian has shown that of 19 theme packages providing a `circle` cursor, only 5 use a *circle* and all the others use some form of .

Why do they do this? Where is the draft/RFC/guideline they follow when assigning a specific meaning to a shape?

Answer (score 1):

Why do they do this is much more a philosophical matter than a programming one. However, to solve the issue of non-intuitive cursors, it might be best to create a [custom cursor](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/custom+cursors) that can be used like in the provided link stated with this code:

```
 # windows:
 $widget configure -cursor "@path/to/cursorfile.cur"
 # unix:
 $widget configure -cursor "@path/to/cursorfile.xbm black"
```

Underneath it uses [Tk_SetOptions](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkLib/SetOptions.html#M14) and a much better source for cursors in the tcl/tk manpage is [Tk_AllocCursorFromObj](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkLib/GetCursor.html)

Comment: only "the cursor will be displayed in the size it was defined", which means that i have to manually take care of HiDPI and whatnot... :-/

Comment: @umläute this [website](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-library/set-0) might be a choice. Never tried, but there are `.ani` and `.cur` files, seemingly free available.